# How to skip jest compile error and run test?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

Here is my vue.js code :

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },
  created() {
    let t = typeof t === 'undefined' ? {} : t; // ISSUE LINE
  }
}
```

The *ISSUE LINE* could run success in browser without any error and pass vue-cli compile process. However, when I try to run this component't test in jest, it could report compile error:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 't' before initialization`

So if the app could run in browser, why it cannot not run in jest? Can I skip this compile error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReferenceError` is not compilation but runtime error. `let t = typeof t === 'undefined' ? {} : t` is invalid ES6 code. `let` is block-scoped and in temporal dead zone until it's assigned, so referring a variable during the assignment is a mistake.

This doesn't work in Jest because Node.js fully supports ES6 and doesn't need to be transpiled to ES5, while in browser build it's transpiled to:

```
var t = typeof t === 'undefined' ? {} : t;
```

`var` declaration is hoisted, so `t` variable is defined during the assignment, so it's the same as:

```
var t; // t === undefined
// ...everything that happens in this scope...
t = typeof t === 'undefined' ? {} : t; // always results in t = {}
```

The condition is useless because it never reaches `else`, a correct way to write it is:

```
let t = {};
```